# What is the correct method to change the SP_Admin password?

Tags: sharepoint-server, security, central-administration

I need to change the sp_admin password in my domain.  I have attempted to make the change in my test bed domain but once I do I cannot access my SharePoint farm.

I started Central Management > Security > Managed Accounts
I logged onto another server and changed the password for sp_admin in AD.
I went back to CMS, selected "Use Existing Password", changed the password and waited for the process to complete.

I have rebooted the SharePoint server and my database server.  I have reset IIS, Checked all of my services and applications pools.

I am unable to access the farm.  I get "Cannot connect to the configuration database"

Where did I go wrong?

But when I try to get into CMS

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here?  If not, what step did you deviate from?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charliechirapuntu/2013/01/16/sharepoint-2010-service-accounts-passwords-change-guide/

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot connect to the configuration database** mean that

- the SQL Server is down or its service is not running. or
- Network Issue. or
- The account used to run the SharePoint application pool didn't have a sufficient privilege to connect to the configuration database.

So Make sure that the SQL Server Service account is not the SharePoint admin account and the SQL Server service status is running and started.

- If it's the admin account so the SQL server Service will be stopped because the password will not be updated automatically . so try to update the service account credential and make sure it's started as mentioned at [SQL Server Service was unable to start](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/04/sql-server-service-is-not-running/)

See also the same issue solution at [Cannot connect to the configuration database during browsing SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/22/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we follow from last couple of years

- change the password IN AD for Sp_Admin account
- Now update the Password in central admin with the option "using existing password" or powershell "`Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword -Identity YourDomain\SP_Admin`"
- Now reset the IIS on the Server to make sure it updated on all servers.

Couple of times, we faced the issue and following workaround fix it

- if you see the issue then 1st run this command [Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607627.aspx)
- in some cases we clear the config cache fix the issue.